# Finding the sum of an integer's digits using this code:

Tags: java

I have confusion over the bit in bold, what exactly does it mean, and how would anyone have figured this out without seeing the solution? The code does work, but I don't understand the bit in bold:

```
public int sumOfDigits(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    n = Math.abs(n); //removes the minus sign from a negative integer
    while (n > 0)
    ***{
        sum += n % 10; //???????????????????????????????????????xplo
        n /= 10;
    }***
    return sum;
}

public void inputAndProcess()
{
    int n = 0;
    Input in = new Input();
    while (true) 
    { 
        System.out.print("Type an integer: ");
        if (in.hasNextInt()) 
        { 
            n = in.nextInt(); 
            break;
        }
        in.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("You did not type an integer, try again."); 
    }
    System.out.print("The sum of the digits of " + n); 
    System.out.println(" is: " + sumOfDigits(n)); 
}   

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Example1_1().inputAndProcess();
}
```

I can't put the selected bit in bold but it is the part of the code covered in ***, and any tips on how to get better at these kinds of archaic codes?

Comment: It's pretty intuitive really.  To add digits you need to isolate them one at a time.  What better method than modulus?  Then divide to move to the next digit.

Comment: Yep, recognized the pattern in literally 2 seconds.

Comment: (You'd do much the same to convert a binary number to decimal.)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (n > 0)
    ***{
        sum += n % 10; //???????????????????????????????????????xplo
        n /= 10;
    }***
```

What's happening here is the sum is the current cumulative sum of the remainder after n has been divided by 10 (% operator is modulus, and is the remainder after the division of the 2 integers).

If you have integer 123:

After first iteration of n:
sum's value is 3 (because remainder of 123 / 10 is 3).
n becomes 12 because 123 divided by 10, and the int value loaded back into n for next iteration

After second iteration of n:
sum's value is 2+3 (because remainder of 12 / 10 is 2).
n becomes 1 because 12 divided by 10, and the int value loaded back into n for next iteration

After third iteration of n:
sum's value is 1+2+3 (because remainder of 1 / 10 is 1).
n becomes 0 because 1 divided by 10, and the int value loaded back into n for next iteration

Answer (score 1):

`% 10` basically tests what the remainder is when the specified number is divided by 10, which is a way to get the last digit from a number. `n /= 10` replaces the value of `n` with the result of the integer division between its original value and 10. Integer division means that the number is divided, but the decimal part is removed, e.g. `128 / 10` is 12. It is used in this context to trim off the last digit of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

When a number is entered, it is taken as an integer value, instead of as one digit at a time. So the code you highlighted basically takes one digit at a time by modding by 10 and then dividing by 10.

For example, if I enter 321, I would calculate 321 % 10 = 1, and the divide 321 by 10, which is 32. Then, 32 % 10 = 2, and 32 divided by 10 is 3. So modding by 10 gets the value of the last digit, and then dividing by 10 takes the digit off.

Once you have all the digits (in this case, 1, 2, and 3), you can simply add them up.

Does that make any sense the way I explained it?